# Firebase Deploy causing multiple errors and not deploying

Tags: firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, expo

Hello I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2D6J10fhA4&t=149s&ab_channel=UnsureProgrammer) in order to do push notifications to multiple devices at once in Expo React Native using Firebase's cloud functions. The push tokens are stored in my RealTime-Database, but when I attempt to integrate this step after running firebase login and firebase init, I updated my index.js file to contain this [code](https://github.com/nathvarun/React-Native-Firebase-Tutorials/blob/master/Project%20Files/6%20Push%20Notifications/Functions/index.js). After saving this file, I attempt to do firebase deploy and I get 70 errors. I tried to deploy it from my app directory, and didnt work, and I tried to do it from my functions directory and that didn't work. I deleted my node_modules and package-lock, and I tried to rerun expo again and clearing my npm cache. Nothing worked. I already had my firebase app initialized somewhere else, could that be the reason why? But my App itself still works, so I am not getting an error saying that the Firebase app is being initialized twice. I really dont know what else do to. Is the ESLint causing all of these errors? Should I run firebase init again without adding ESLint? Please let me know. My errors are below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When deploying your code, by default, your code is linted using a tool called [ESLint](https://eslint.org).

The "errors" you see are `eslint` complaining about trivial things like missing semicolons at the end of a line, using `'` instead of `"`, improperly indented code, among other things. If you ever don't understand what a rule is trying to do, you can visit `https://eslint.org/docs/rules/{rule-name}` (such as `https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi`).

As shown in the error message, you can use `eslint . --fix` to automatically fix most of these. Just enter into your `functions` directory and execute `eslint . --fix`.

Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut for automatically formatting your code to your rules. In VSCode for example, this shortcut is `Alt+Shift+F`.

Comment: Thank you! this fixed my error. Now i have to figure out how to push notifications to multiple devices with expo. i will post another question for that.